# connection exception :CannotGetJdbcConnectionException: Could not load JDBC driver class ["com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver";]

Tags: sql-server-2008, class, jdbc, driver

I have an web application in struts 1.3 which contain hibernate as ORM and spring as contextloaded AOP or as it is in general use. 
I'm trying to deploy it in tomcat 6.0 server. earlier it was connected to mysql and it was working fine but now I want to connect it with  MS Sql server 2008 so I downloaded "sqljdbc" and "sqljdbc4" jar and placed it into "C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 6.0\webapps\web1\WEB-INF\lib" location of my system. I have java 7 installed in my system.when I trying to run then its giving exception :

**org.apache.jasper.JasperException: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSource' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/applicationContext-hibernate.xml]: Error setting property values; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.PropertyAccessExceptionsException: PropertyAccessExceptionsException (1 errors); nested propertyAccessExceptions are: [org.springframework.beans.MethodInvocationException: Property 'driverClassName' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.jdbc.CannotGetJdbcConnectionException: Could not load JDBC driver class ["com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver";]; nested exception is java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: "com/microsoft/sqlserver/jdbc/SQLServerDriver";]**

My jdbc property file entry is :

```
jdbc.driverClassName="com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver";
jdbc.url="jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433/databaseName=DB_1"
jdbc.username="dipak";
jdbc.password="";

hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServer2008Dialect
```

> ApplicationContext-Hibernate.xml

entry is :

```
<bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="${jdbc.driverClassName}" />
    <property name="url" value="${jdbc.url}" />
    <property name="username" value="${jdbc.username}" />
    <property name="password" value="${jdbc.password}" />
</bean>
```

Please help me to solve this problem, I Google a lot and tried many solutions but not get success yet, So any help would be much appreciated.

If you need any other/more information then please let me know.

Thanks,
-Dipak

Answer (score 1):

Wrong spot for that JAR. Tomcat 6 and higher expects to find it in the Tomcat server /lib, not your application WEB-INF/lib.  Move it and you'll see better results.

Make sure that your URL syntax is correct:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms378428(v=sql.90).aspx

Comment: Thanks for you quick response but I have placed it (sqljdbc" and "sqljdbc4" jar) in both the places i.e "C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 7.0\lib" and "C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 7.0\webapps\web1\WEB-INF\lib" but getting same exception.

Comment: No, not both places.  Just one: Tomcat /lib.  Remove it from WEB-INF/lib.

Comment: actually I got it working. I was doing mistake in my JDBC property file that I was giving all connection properties under double quote ("") that's not correct way and this was the fault I was doing. Now I corrected it and got it working.

Comment: @user2536341: What changes you did exactly? I am facing same problem